# Making a table fill the whole page horizontally

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to fill a table over the whole page (horizontally). I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}\caption{Descriptive statistics of variables}\label{Statistics of all countries}
 \toprule
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}LllllllllL@{}}
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Interest rate (basis points)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Debt-to-GDP (\%)} & \\
    Countries & $\mu$ & Max &  Min & $\sigma$ & $\mu$ & Max & Min & $\sigma$ \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
      \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
    Austria & 300.19 & 544.98 & -78.17 & 174.18 & 73.34 & 85.90 & 65.00 & 6.25  \\
    Belgium &  299.77 & 573.61 & -41.65 & 176.12 & 102.99 & 117.40 & 87.3 & 7.40 \\
    Finland &  258.71 & 533.34 & -241.38 & 186.23 & 44.19 & 64.20 & 28.70 & 10.54\\

    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
      \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
        \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
 Full sample & 720.47 & 3816.33 & 38.62 & 833.42 & 1.66 & 21.45 & 0.00 & 2.83
 \\
\end{tabularx}
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\captionsetup{width=\textwidth}
\caption*{\textit{Descriptive statistics of all countries over the years 2000 until 2020 Q2 , excluding the crisis. The mean, maximum, minimum and standard deviation is given.}  }
\end{table}
```

I intentionally left out multiple rows. I tried to fill the page using \textwidth but it is not working.

Comment: How is the `L` column type defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately is not entirely clear, how should your table looks like:

- defined are 11 columns, but used only 9
- table lines had not to be outside `tabularx` environment (or any others)
- I would use `S` defined in the `siunitx` package columns for numbers, which are in them aligned at decimal points

After cleanup your code fragment, the possible MWE (Minimal Working Example) with your table) can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, 
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcx{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{C}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Descriptive statistics of variables}
\label{Statistics of all countries}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l 
                     S[table-format= 3.2]
                     S[table-format= 4.2]
                     S[table-format=-3.2]
                *{3}{S[table-format= 3.2]} 
                *{2}{S[table-format= 2.2]}
                             }
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Interest rate (basis points)} 
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Debt-to-GDP (\%)}              \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-5}
    \cmidrule(l){6-9}
Countries   & \mcx{$\mu$} & \mcx{Max} & \mcx{Min} & \mcx{$\sigma$}
            & \mcx{$\mu$} & \mcx{Max} & \mcx{Min} & \mcx{$\sigma$}\\
    \hline
Austria     & 300.19      & 544.98    &  -78.17     & 174.18 
            &  73.34      & 85.90     &   65.00     & 6.25      \\
Belgium     & 299.77      & 573.61    &  -41.65     & 176.12 
            & 102.99      & 117.40    &   87.3      & 7.40      \\
Finland     & 258.71      & 533.34    & -241.38     & 186.23 
            & 44.19       & 64.20     &   28.70     & 10.54     \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}
    \cmidrule(l){2-5}
    \cmidrule(l){6-9}
Full sample & 720.47      & 3816.33   & 38.62     & 833.42 
            & 1.66        & 21.45     & 0.00      & 2.83      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \captionsetup{font={small, it}}
\caption*{Descriptive statistics of all countries over the years 2000 until 2020 Q2 , excluding the crisis. The mean, maximum, minimum and standard deviation is given.}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Looks really nice! I will use this as a template for personal future use.

Comment: Tabularx without any X type column? Wouldn't it make sense to replace l with X here? Alternatively, you could also use tabular* on combination with @{\extracolsep{\fill}}}.

Comment: @leandriis, actually it has eight `C` columns derived from `X` columns which are hidden in the definition of the `mcx` :-)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I entirely overlooked them. Are they also the reason for the slightly off-centered appearance of the first "Min"? (I hope that's not an optical illusion that's tricking me here.)

Comment: @leandriis, it seems so, but haven't time to investigate why this happen (I didn't try, if the same is with old version of `siunitx`. Now I'm going on the way where i will three day off internet connection :-)